# Fetch the data of parent model into static::saving() boot function

Tags: laravel, eloquent, computed-values

I want to use data from the parent model to run the `saving()` function in the child model

Previously, I inserted a computed data to the table in model "Loan" but now I need to insert it into a child model "`InterestAmount`"

**Loan.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Loan extends Model
{

    protected $fillable ['amount','interest','status','duration','member_id','loan_type_id','interest_type_id','loan_payment_type_id'];

    //protected $appends = 'interest_amount

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::saving(function($model) {
            $model->interest_amount = ($model->amount/100 )* $model->interest;
        });
    }

    public function interest_amount()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InterestAmount::class,'loan_id','id');
    }

}
```

I want to remove the saving function from Loan.php and use as below.

**Interest.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class InterestAmount extends Model
{
    public function loan()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(Loan::class,'loan_id','id');
    }

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::saving(function($model) {
            $model->interest_amount = ($model->amount/100 )* $model->interest;
        }); 
    }
}
```

How do I fetch "amount" and "interest" in this function?

Comment: Does your `InterestAmount` table contains the interest_amount column ?

Comment: I see some errors on your code, like, the `loan()` function is not returning anything. Are you sure you copied the right code?

Comment: i created InterestAmount model since interest_amount is a multi valued attribute and thus i have i create a different model to store multiple interest amount for a given loan

Comment: @namelivia yes. sorry my  mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The `$model` variable inside `InterestAmount` model refers to an `InterestAmount` object :

```
static::saving(function($model){
    $model->interest_amount = ($model->loan->amount/100 )* $model->loan->interest;
});
```

Then you need to get the related `loan` using your relationship method `loan()` then get the properties `amount/interest`.

**NOTE:** As @namelivia's comment says you're missing the `return` in the `loan()` method:

```
public function loan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Loan::class,'loan_id','id');
}
```

Comment: more importantly.. data in table "interest_amounts" needs to be inserted automatically once loan data is inserted since i split table "loan" as "interest_amount" to insert "interest amount" which is a multi valued attribute. can i get some help?? i was thinking of using event and listener but i have no idea how.